# Django database design help

Tags: django, data-modeling

I'm designing a project management site, The user needs to enter the hardware required for the project in addition to other details. For example,

project_name, project_location
and hardware:
A (5 units)
B (10 units)
C (1 unit)

The number of hardware types per project is not fixed. How do I design this model?

Comment: I'm just wondering (having listened to the SE podcasts recently): is this question too localized?

Answer (score 0):

Could this do the job?

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    location = models.CharField()

class Hardware(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class HardwareUnits(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    hardware = models.ForeignKey(Hardware)
    unit_count = models.IntegerField()
```

If you use the Admin interface, you could attach inlines of HardwareUnits in ProjectAdmin, and the user will be able to chose the hardwares and the number of units for each of them directly in the Project admin edit page.